# Lvalue/rvalue -nes encoding for universal references

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lvalue, rvalue, universal-reference

I've been reading Effective Modern C++ and the following thing caught my attention:

In Item 28 Scott writes:

> Together, these observations about universal references and
> lvalue/rvalue encoding mean that for this template
>
> `template<typename T> void func(T&& param);`
>
> the deduced template parameter T will encode
> whether the argument passed to param was an lvalue or an rvalue. The
> encoding mechanism is simple. When an lvalue is passed as an argument,
> T is deduced to be an lvalue reference. When an rvalue is passed, T is
> deduced to be a non-reference. (Note the asymmetry: lvalues are
> encoded as lvalue references, but rvalues are encoded as
> non-references.)

Can somebody explain why such encoding mechanism was chosen?

I mean if we will follow reference collapsing rules than usage of aforementioned template with rvalue yields rvalue reference. And as far as I can tell everything would work just the same if it were deduced as rvalue reference. Why is it encoded as non-reference?

Comment: BTW, the term "universal reference" didn't catch on, and the committee chose to use [forwarding reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf) instead.

Comment: I think your question might be the same as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282705/a-failure-to-instantiate-function-templates-due-to-universal-forward-reference

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm esp. #7. IIRC, Howard Hinnant once stated that introducing some `&&&` solely for forwarding references probably wasn't going to be accepted at that time (as a third reference kind).

Comment: OTOH, that doesn't seem to answer why `T` isn't deduced to be `A&&`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you need to pass `param` around. In fact, you need to store it for lifetime purposes. As is, you'd just use `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct store { T val; };

template<typename T> void func(T&& param) {
    store<T> s{std::forward<T>(param)};
}
```

This works because if `param` got passed in by lvalue, `T` would be an lvalue reference type, and we're just copying the reference. If `param` got passed in by rvalue, we need to take ownership - `T` is a non-reference type, so we end up move-constructing into `s`.

The fact that I can just use `T` here as the template argument for `store`, instead of `std::conditional_t<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, T, std::remove_reference_t<T>>` is probably not an accident.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If `store<T>` is destroyed after `func` returns, then passing in rvalue references would work just as well as passing in lvalue references. If `store<T>` is persisted after `func` returns, then lvalue references can also end up invalidated just as rvalue references can be.

Comment: I think the point was that it is just simpler to work afterwards with T than with T&& so providing we can achieve the same functionality with T it gets deduced as T.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking the wrong way around. Instead of asking "why not always make `T` a reference type", look at it from the other side:

Suppose you have `template <typename T> void f(T&&t)`.

Calling it as `int i; f(i);`, some `T` is needed such that `T&&` resolves to `int&`. What's the simplest `T` that can achieve that? It's `int&`.

Calling it as `f(0);`, some `T` is needed such that `T&&` resolves to `int&&`. What's the simplest `T` that can achieve that? It's `int`, not `int&&`.

`int&&` simply doesn't really have any advantages here.