# Why can't C++ deduce T in a call to Foo<T>::Foo(T&&)?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Given the following template struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T&&) {}
};
```

This compiles, and `T` is deduced to be `int`:

```
auto f = Foo(2);
```

But this doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/hAA9TE

```cpp
int x = 2;
auto f = Foo(x);

/*
<source>:12:15: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'Foo'
    auto f = Foo(x);
             ^

<source>:7:5: note: candidate function [with T = int] not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&' for 1st argument
    Foo(T&&) {}
    ^
*/
```

However, `Foo<int&>(x)` is accepted.

But when I add a seemingly redundant user-defined deduction guide, it works:

```
template<typename T>
Foo(T&&) -> Foo<T>;
```

Why can't `T` be deduced as `int&` without a user-defined deduction guide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32282705/11683?

Comment: That question seems to be about template types such as `Foo<T<A>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the confusion here arises because there is a specific exception for the synthesized deduction guides regarding forwarding references.

It is true that the candidate function for the purpose of class template argument deduction generated from the constructor and the one generated from the user-defined deduction guide look exactly the same, i.e.:

```
template<typename T>
auto f(T&&) -> Foo<T>;
```

but for the one generated from the constructor, `T&&` is a simple rvalue reference, while it is a *forwarding reference* in the user-defined case. This is specified by [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#deduct.call-3) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659, emphasize mine):

> A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter **that does not represent a template parameter of a class template** (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).

Therefore the candidate synthesized from the class constructor will not deduce `T` as if from a forwarding reference (which could deduce `T` to be a lvalue reference, so that `T&&` is also a lvalue reference), but instead will only deduce `T` as non-reference, so that `T&&` is always an rvalue reference.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer. Do you know **why** there is an exception for class template parameters in the rules for forwarding references?

Comment: @jtbandes This seems to have been changed as a result of a comment by the US national body, see paper [p0512r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0512r0.pdf). I couldn't find the comment though. My guess for the rationale is that if you write a constructor taking a rvalue reference, you usually expect it to work the same way whether you specify a `Foo<int>(...)` or just `Foo(...)`, which is not the case with forwarding references (which could deduce `Foo<int&>` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that, since the **class** is templated on `T`, in the constructor `Foo(T&&)` we are *not* performing type deduction; We always have an r-value reference. That is, the constructor for `Foo` actually looks like this:

```
Foo(int&&)
```

`Foo(2)` works because `2` is a prvalue.

`Foo(x)` does not because `x` is an lvalue that cannot bind to `int&&`. You could do `std::move(x)` to cast it to the appropriate type ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/58CQXn))

`Foo<int&>(x)` works just fine because the constructor becomes `Foo(int&)` due to reference collapsing rules; initially it's `Foo((int&)&&)` which collapses to `Foo(int&)` per the standard.

In regards to your "redundant" deduction guide: 
Initially there is a default template deduction guide for the code that basically acts like a helper function like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T&&) {}
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T> MakeFoo(std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T> value)
{
   return Foo<T>(std::move(value));
}

//... 
auto f = MakeFoo(x);
```

This is because the standard dictates that this (fictional) template method has the same template parameters as the class (Just `T`) followed by any template parameters as the constructor (none in this case; the constructor is not templated). Then, the types of the function parameters are the same as those in the constructor. In our case, after instantiating `Foo<int>`, the constructor looks like `Foo(int&&)`, an rvalue-reference in other words. Hence the usage of `add_rvalue_reference_t` above.

Obviously this doesn't work.

When you added your "redundant" deduction guide:

```
template<typename T>
Foo(T&&) -> Foo<T>;
```

You allowed the compiler to distinguish that, despite any kind of reference attached to `T` in the constructor (`int&`, `const int&`, or `int&&` etc.), you intended the type inferred for the class to be without reference (just `T`). This is because we suddenly *are* performing type inference.

Now we generate another (fictional) helper function that looks like this:

```
template<class U>
Foo<U> MakeFoo(U&& u)
{
   return Foo<U>(std::forward<U>(u));
}

// ...
auto f = MakeFoo(x);
```

(Our calls to the constructor are redirected to the helper function for the purposes of class template argument deduction, so `Foo(x)` becomes `MakeFoo(x)`).

This allows `U&&` to become `int&` and `T` to become simply `int`

Comment: The second level of templating does not seem necessary; what value does it provide? Can you provide a link to some documentation that clarifies *why* T&& is always treated as an rvalue reference here?

Comment: But if T has not been deduced yet, what does "any type convertible to T" mean?

Comment: You're quick to offer a workaround, but can you focus more on the explanation for the reason why it doesn't work unless you modify it in some way?  Why doesn't it work as is?  "`x` is an lvalue that cannot bind to `int&&`" but someone who doesn't understand will be puzzled that `Foo<int&>(x)` could work but wasn't figured out automatically - I think we all want deeper understanding of why.

Comment: @Wyck: I've updated the post to focus more on the why.

Comment: @Wyck The real reason is very simple: the standard *specifically turned off* perfect forwarding semantics in synthesized deduction guides to prevent surprises.